# Site Classifications and Better Security Control/Alerts

Tags: security, alert, irm, dlp

We are looking into using Site Classifications for our SharePoint environments.  Classifications are great in that you can apply a global image/stamp/badge @ the top title section of the site and also put the site in 'Read Only' mode or delete the site if needed.

What more can we get out of site classifications?  Can we apply rules and setup alerts that utilize site classifications and security measures so we are notified if security infractions are happening?

Say I have 5 example classifications >> Low, medium, high, confidential, classified

I want a rule to look in all 'Confidential' and 'Classified' sites for users under a certain domain or users with an email of '@public.com', and get an email / alert they have been added so we can deal with this infraction.

We are looking into CASB, IRM & DLP in SharePoint 2013/2016, but I'm not seeing anything as of yet that will perform these alerts.